# Dialogflow API - Set location on request

Tags: dialogflow-es

I have a question regarding the Dialogflow API. I have a dialog with multiple stages. Let's just call them stage 1, 2 and 3. The deeper you are in the conversation, the higher the number. The welcome intent is 1, second 2 and the third 3.

There are three buttons (1, 2 and 3). The should set the context (or something similar..) when requesting the conversation. So button 3 connects to the dialog at 3, skipping intent 1 and 2.

I was wondering how to do this using the API? I tried setting events but somehow it's not working.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you please reformulate your question? What do you mean with "dialog"? Ho can you get to button 3 without seeing the other 2 first (as you said the deeper you go, the higher the number)...

Comment: Thanks for your repsonse. I figured out that, for using events, the contexts should match as well. I now use the Dialogflow API in the following way: GET request the intent by ID, save the events and contexts, then do an POST :detectintent request with contexts and event.